# List of filenames modified within 1 week

Tags: python, linux, logging

I've got a segment of my script which will create a list of files to scan through for key words..

The problem is, the log files collectively are around 11gb. When I use `grep` in the shell to search through them, it takes around 4 or 5 minutes. When I do it with my python script, it just hangs the server to the extent where I need to reboot it.

Doesn't seem right that it would cause the whole server to crash, but in reality I don't need it to scroll through all the files, just those which were modified within the last week.

I've got this so far:

```
 logs = [log for log in glob('/var/opt/cray/log/p0-current/*') if not os.path.isdir(log)]
```

I assume I will need to add something prior to this to initially filter out the wrong files?

I've been playing with `os.path.getmtime` in this format:

```
logs = [log for log in glob('/var/opt/cray/log/p0-current/*') if not os.path.isdir(log)]

for log in logs:
    mtime = os.path.getmtime(log)
    if mtime < "604800":
       do-stuff (create a new list? Or update logs?)
```

That's kind of where I am now, and it doesn't work but I was hoping there was something more elegant I could do with the list inline?

Comment: If you want elegant use `man find`.  Otherwise try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example. That makes it easier for us to help you.

Comment: Not sure that you mean, I didn't know `find()` was a thing in Python. I'm learning. I thought my explanation of my requirements was Minimal, Complete and Verifiable. Looking to add further trimming to the conditions which build my list. So currently the list `logs` contains a huge number of filenames, but I'd like to trim that down to files which have a modified time of less than 604800 seconds (1 week) I put it in seconds, because when I use `os.path.getmtime(log)` and then print out the results, I get some huge numbers. I looked up `os.path.getmtime()` and found that the results are in secs

Comment: @StephenRauch - Can I use something similar to regular shell? `find /path/to/logs -type f -mtime -7` - This would be much cleaner. In the 2 weeks I've been learning Python.. everything seems much more long winded than a regular shell script. I'm sure it's my lack of understanding, but I'm struggling to find the benefits of Python over Bash at the moment.

Comment: Yes, the `man find` comment was a reference to the man page for find.  For certain things the command line tools are a lot more elegant since they was designed for these things.  But... as soon as your needs get more varied or have much depth, python is a *very* good thing to know.  If you are trying to develop more competence with python I would encourage you to continue with the project presented here. However, if you want some help from SO users, you should create an MCVE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on how many filenames and how little memory (512MB VPS?), it's possible you're running out of memory creating two lists of all the filenames (one from `glob` and one from your list comprehension.) Not necessarily the case but it's all I have to go on.

Try switching to `iglob` (which uses `os.scandir` under the hood and returns an iterator) and using a generator expression and see if that helps.

Also, `getmtime` gets a time, not an interval from now.

```
import os
import glob
import time

week_ago = time.time() - 7 * 24 * 60 * 60
log_files = (
    x for x in glob.iglob('/var/opt/cray/log/p0-current/*')
    if not os.path.isdir(x)
    and os.path.getmtime(x) > week_ago
)
for filename in log_files:
    pass  # do something
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, I'll have a quick play around with what you've suggested. Also, I checked and it is indeed running out of memory.

Comment: This works very well! I tested alongside `find /var/opt/cray/log/p0-current -mtime -7 -maxdepth 1` and the above responds with the same list, so it works well. I don't get the `and os.path.getmtime(x) > week_ago` In my head this says is the mtime is greater than 1 week? Or am I missing something?

Comment: mtime here is when, not how long ago, so > is for after